# Tangent plane at a common point to two closed regular surfaces in ${\mathbb R}^3$.

Tags: differential-geometry

I have two closed regular surfaces of class $C^2$ in ${\mathbb R}^3$, say $S_1$ and $S_2$, with $S_2$ enclosing $S_1$ and $S_1 \cap S_2\neq \emptyset$. I don't know how to justify the following: For each $P\in S_1 \cap S_2$ holds that the tangent plane of $S_1$ at $P$ is the same tangent plane of $S_2$ at $P$.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by "enclosing"?

Comment: @fuglede: that one is inside of the other, what else?

Comment: it's like a closed bag within another closed bag. I don't know if you understand me @fuglede.

Comment: Where did you find the statement ?

Comment: @Tony Piccolo , in the problems 2.6.2 and 2.6.3 (pag 107-108) of the book Differential Geometry
of Curves and Surfaces-A Concise Guide, the author is Victor Andreevich Toponogov. In this two problems $S_2$ is an esphere in the problem 2.6.2 and is a hyperboloid in the problem 2.6.3.

Comment: It seems that the proof should boil down to proving something similar to the following: Suppose $f_0$ and $f_1$ are two $C^2$ functions $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f_0 \leq f_1$. If at some $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$, $f_0(x) = f_1(x)$, then the tangent planes to the graphs of $f_0$ and $f_1$ at $x$ are the same. (Taylor's theorem might be useful to prove such a fact.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment by Phillip Andreae is essentially an answer. Given $P\in S_1\cap S_2$, choose a coodinate system in which $P=(0,0,0)$, the tangent plane to $S_2$ is horizontal, and the "up" direction of $z$-axis corresponds to the inward normal to $S_2$. In this coordinate system the surface $S_2$ is locally given by $z=f (x,y)$ with $f (0,0)=0$ and $\nabla f (0,0)=(0,0)$. The function $f $ is $C^2$ smooth.

Suppose the tangent to $S_1$ at $P$ is not the plane $z=0$. Then it's some other plane, call it  $M$. Take a point $(a,b,c)$ on $M$ with $c<0$.  The definition of tangent plane implies that the distance from the surface $S_1$ to the point $(ta,tb,tc)$ is $o(t)$. Therefore, for sufficiently small $t$ this distance is less than $|tc|/2$, and the $z$-coordinate of the corresponding point of $S_1$ is $<-tc/2$. On the other hand, since $S_1$ lies above $S_2$ near $P$, its points satisfy the inequality $z\ge f(x,y)$ when $x^2+y^2$ is sufficiently small. A contradiction.